# How to retrieve values of nested objects in a Mongo DB document using java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a document like below:

```
"application" : "test",
"QA1" : {
    "url" : "https://google.co.in",
    "db" : {
        "userName" : "user",
        "password" : "pswd"
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the value "https://google.co.in" by calling the key "url".

While using the below shell command, I am able to retrieve the value as expected.
**db.getCollection('Application_Data').findOne({"application":"test"}).QA1.url**

But when I convert it to java code, it is throwing me null pointer exception:

```
cursor = collection.find(Filters.eq("application","test")).iterator();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            value=cursor.next().get("QA1.url").toString();
            break;
        }
```

I also tried with projection like below to get the required values:

```
cursor = collection.find(Filters.and(Filters.eq("application","test"))).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("QA1.url"),Projections.excludeId())).iterator();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().get("QA1").toString());
        }
```

This is giving me the output as below:

> Document{{url=https://google.co.in}}

It is still not giving me the exact value. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb Documents are nested. So say, in your example, when you do `cursor.next().get("QA1")`, you get the Document under "QA1" property.

So the way to achieve what you want is
`cursor.next().get("QA1").get("url")`. That, with proper error handling (think exceptions).

A better way to do what you want is to use a mapper like spring-data-mongodb that would map the JSON response of mongodb into a java object for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Document class's `getEmbedded` method to extract the nested field's value.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = cursor.next();
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    String urlValue = doc.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("QA1","url"), String.class);
    System.out.println(urlValue);  // output below
}
```

The result is as expected - a string: `https://google.co.in`